# Horizontal positioning of embedded DIV elements

Tags: html, css, positioning

[image: Horizontal positioning of embedded DIV elements]

Please help me design the above example in HTML and CSS. Explanation:

- Each rectangle is a div.
- There is one container DIV with black colour and surrounded by A B C D corners.
- Inside the container div there are two TIER1 divs, light grey and dark grey.
- Those TIER1 divs themselves contain child divs and they can contain other child divs.
- In other words, NESTED divs. Thus: parent contains the child.
- Important: the horizontal positioning has to be absolute; simply putting the next div right next to the previous one is not what i want. As you can see the red div does not start at the start of the light grey TIER1 div; this is intentional.
- The different TIERs should have a vertical indentation; as you can see TIER3 has a margin at the top so that the parent div is visible.

They way i like to implement this is as follows:

- Stylesheet contains generic CSS code; the HTML page contains the positioning of each child DIV using 'left=Xpx' or 'margin-left:Xpx' combined with 'width=Xpx'.
- The nesting does not have to be perfect; my code will generate the child divs so that they do not exceed their parent div. So the actual HTML code may just be a bunch of divs inside one container div; it just has to LOOK like they are nested. I think this is easier than actually nest divs in the HTML code itself.
- The DIVs get their colour using a simple 'background=#XXX'.

In other words, i want to play with a 'canvas' and draw rectangles in the perspective of position 0,0 = A and 100,100 = D. The HTML code will provide those coordinates, from start (left-top) to end (right-bottom).

I have been playing with display:table, float:left, margin-left and other stuff, but can't get this to work. Horizontal positioning of div elements has always been a tricky side of CSS for me. But i think this can work. Please help me out, thanks a bunch!

Comment: You need to provide code as to what you have tried.  This isn't the place to request someone to code for you.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, i'm not asking for drop-in code; just pointers on how to achieve the desired result. Some sample code when i was still using tables:

`<div id="timekeeper">
<table class="timekeeper"><tbody><tr>
<td style="width:15.748%" title="procedures: 802.6 ms"></td>
<td style="width:14.995%" title="readpreferences: 764.2 ms"></td>
<td style="width:0.005%" title="authentication: 0.3 ms"></td>
<td style="width:0.71%" title="sanitize: 36.2 ms"></td>
<td style="width:24.167%" title="content: 1231.6 ms"></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved the issue, here is the solution for anyone who has similar issues:

```
<!-- container DIV uses relative position -->
<div style="position:relative">

 <!-- sub DIVs use absolute positioning and can be positioned with CSS: -->
 <div style="position:absolute; left:100px; top:10px; width:200px; background:#00f"></div>

 <!-- you can have as many DIVs as you want, and they may overlap each other, they will not push each other out of the way -->
 <div style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:20px; width:200px; background:#f00"></div>

</div>
```